# Form focus on custom element when required hidden field is not filled

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with a hidden required input element. I will be setting the value of this input through javascript based on some other computations.

If the value is empty and the form submits, I want the `.focusable` div to be focused instead.

Try removing the `hidden` attribute from the example below and submit the form (without entering any value in the input) to see what I mean. If the value of the hidden input is empty, the form should focus on the div instead of the input element. How can I do this using javascript?

```css
.focusable {
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.focusable:focus,
focusable:focus {
  outline: 2px solid green;
}

button {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
}

form {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input required hidden />
  <div class="focusable">
    This div should focus when form is submitted
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input that you have provided is `required`, the focus will always go there on submit if it is `empty`, if it is `hidden`, you'll get an error. If you want to focus the `div` instead of the `input` you cannot mark it as `required` but handle it programmatically. For focusing the `div` you have to put `tabindex` attribute, you can try the below snippet.

```js
function submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const hInput = e.target.querySelector('input[hidden]');
  const focusable = e.target.querySelector('.focusable');
  if (!hInput.value) {
    focusable.focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    // code to submit the form
  }
}
```

```css
.focusable {
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.focusable:focus,
focusable:focus {
  outline: 2px solid green;
}

button {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
}

form {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="submitForm(event)">
  <input tabIndex='-1' hidden />
  <div tabIndex='0' class="focusable">
    This div should focus when form is submitted
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submt</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` wasn't working for me and the form was directly submitting. I used `e.returnValue = false` instead.